# $GL_n(F)$ is not abelian for $n\ge 2$ counter example?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I am asked to prove that for $n \ge 2$, the group $GL_n(F)$, where $F$ is any field, is non-abelian. I figure this amounts to finding a counter-example for all such $n$. It wasn't hard, but I'm having a bit of trouble remembering how to prove my counterexample. I'm not sure if this is the optimal way to do this problem, but just something I was toying around with. So for $n=2$, let's say $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & a  \\
0 & a  \end{array} \right)$ for some $a \in A$ and let $B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0  \\
0 & 1  \end{array} \right)$ where $1 \in F$ is the multiplicative identity. Both $A$ and $B$ are in $GL_2(F)$ since they are invertible. Then of course $AB \neq BA$. 
I know that if I were to do a $3 \times 3$ matrix, I could just add a row and a column of $3$ zeroes each (so let's say $A'$ and $B'$), then $A'B' = AB$ with $AB$ also having an extra row/column of $3$ zeroes, and hence would be a counter example for $n=3$. I could then keep doing this, and as such, will have provided a counter-example for all $n\ge2$. But I'm not sure how I would prove this by induction. Of course base case is $2$, but then would I just say "attach $n-2$ rows and $n-2$ columns, each containing $n$ zeroes?" It doesn't sound to formal to me. I have a feeling I did something like this in linear algebra, but it's escaping me right now. Any help would be appreciated.
Also, this my first question of this type, so if the format is not correct or my explanation is incoherent, I apologize.

Comment: why not just add 1's on the diagonal, and zeroes elsewhere?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan That is indeed a good idea, thank you. I'm kinda new to this whole thing so these examples don't come right away to me

Answer (score 1):

As Prahlad comments, if you have a counterexample with $2\times2$ matrices $A$ and $B$, then the pair of block diagonal matrices $A\oplus I_{n-2}$ and $B\oplus I_{n-2}$ will form a counterexample for any $n>2$.

However, your counterexample works only if $a^2\ne a$. It does not work on $GF(2)$. To construct a counterexample that works over all fields, consider some $2\times2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ whose elements belong to $\{0,1\}$ (because $0$ and $1$ are contained in *all* fields) and $BA=0$ but $AB\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider the field with ONLY $0$ and $1$ as elements.